# Unnecessary DS_BCAST_INNER after GROUP BY in Redshift

Tags: database, query-optimization, amazon-redshift

I have a problem and would like to know if there is a solution to this.

I am having absolutely unnecessarily table broadcast(DS_BCAST_INNER) in my query.

Imagine you have Table1 and Table2 both having the same distkey MediaId.

When I join both tables directly there is no redistribution which is good. But when I try to do something similar to:

```
WITH t1
AS
(
SELECT MediaId, ... FROM Table1 ...predicates... GROUP BY MediaId, ...
),
t2 AS
(
SELECT MediaId, ... FROM Table2 ...predicates... GROUP BY MediaId, ...
)
Select ... FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t.MediaId = t2.MediaId ....
```

I see DS_BCAST_INNER in execution plan shown by explain command while it is obviously useless.

How can I avoid it?

Comment: I am having this same issue.  Did you get it figured out?

Answer (score 1):

Run an `EXPLAIN` on this and look at the underlying data types of your tables (before the group by).

I've seen this recently where Table1 was a `char(36)` and Table2 has a `varchar(36)`; this caused a cast and a broadcast, since the hashing of a char and a varchar is (probably) different.  (The varchar will have a length prefix that is probably being included in the hash... :-( )

The data types on the join must be EXACTLY the same, not nearly.  E.g. an `INT` to a `BIGINT` will probably have the same issue.

(Haven't checked this, but possibly even nullability?)